# CoreData and relationship to classes implementing a protocol

Tags: ios, core-data

I am building an ios app and I have the following problem:

I have say a class `Animal` which contains classes `Cats` and `Dogs`. These classes in turn have subclasses `DomesticCats`, `WildCats` (resp. `DomesticDogs`, `WildDogs`) which contain species of cats and dogs, some of which are domestic animals and some others are not.

I have another class `PetOwner` which will contain a to-many relationship `petsSet` to instances of either `DomesticCats` or `DomesticDogs`, the inverse relationship being `owner`.

Is there a way to model this relationship in the CoreDate model of my app ?
It it were not for CoreData I would define a Protocol `<DomesticAnimal>` that both `DomesticCats` and `DomesticDogs` would implement, containing (among others) the property `owner`, but I don't think I can mix that with the CoreData model?

Or do I need to create a to-many relationship form `PetOwner` to `Animal` in my CoreData model, but then can I enforce that only classes implementing `<DomesticAnimal>` will ever be added to the `petsSet` of a `PetOwner` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest an alternative that may make managing your data easier.

Add a new Entity and name it `AnimalType`, with one string attribute that you can add the types "domestic" and "wild" into, and one relationship with the entity `Animal` perhaps named `typeAnimal`, the inverse of which would reside as a relationship in the entity `Animal`, perhaps named `animalType`.

That way each entity `Animal` can have a type either "domestic" or "wild".

Then when you need a data set of only "domestic" animals for example, you can run a fetch on the Entity `Animal` with the predicate set to `animalType = "domestic"`.